# How to use user defined DLL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to use user defined ASP.NET MVC application DLL in another ASP.MVC application?

Comment: what is a 'user defined asp.net mvc application dll'? how do you want to use it?  What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: i have a mvc application dll and i want to use dat dll in my own application

Comment: I'm sorry but without details of what's actually in that DLL and how you intend to use it, I can't see a way to answer your question.  Darin has been incredibly generous and given you the best possible answer given how little information you've given.

Answer (score 0):

You could add any valid .NET assembly as reference to the project. By default ASP.NET MVC uses an ASP.NET web application model (in contrast to a website) and thus it is compiled into an assembly. So you could reference the generated assembly (from the `bin` folder) into the new ASP.NET MVC application. Once you have done that you will be able to access the public types defined inside this assembly.

But bear in mind that this is a bad idea in general. If you want to share some common functionality between multiple ASP.NET MVC applications I would recommend you externalizing this functionality into a separate class library and then reference this library into each web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DLL, you can add it to the bin directory (you may need to do it through the file system - outside of Visual Studio project).

After you add it to the Bin directory, you can then add a reference to it (References directory).  Once you do that, you should have full access to its methods, etc.).